# How can I convert these two queries in a loop into a single JOINed query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting, query-optimization

I am currently trying to get data from my table (mostKills by Weapon in a table with over 300 kills). Initially I did a normal query

```
$q = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `kills`") or die($mysql->error);
```

but when I tried to

```
            $query2 = $mysql->query("SELECT `killerID`, COUNT(`killerID`) AS tot_kills FROM `kills` WHERE `killText` LIKE '%$gun%' GROUP BY `killerID` ORDER BY `tot_kills` DESC;") or die($mysql->error);
            $kData = $query2->fetch_assoc();

            $query3 = $mysql->query("SELECT `Username` FROM `players` WHERE `ID` = '" . $kData['killerID'] . "'") or die($mysql->error);
            $uData = $query3->fetch_assoc();

            $array[$gun]['Kills']++;
            $array[$gun]['Gun'] = $gun;
            $array[$gun]['BestKiller'] = $uData['Username'];
            $array[$gun]['killAmount'] = $kData['tot_kills'];

            function sortByKills($a, $b) {
                return  $b['Kills'] - $a['Kills'];
            }

            usort($array, 'sortByKills');

            foreach($array as $i => $value) 
            {
                // table here
            }
```

I had to do it in a while loop, which caused there to be around 600 queries, and that is obviously not acceptable. Do you have any tips on how I can optimize this, or even turn this into a single query?

I heared JOIN is good for this, but I don't know much about it, and was wondering if you guys could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

I added a `inner join` and added a `username` to your select clause. The `MIN()` is just a way to include the `username` column in the `select` and will not have an impact on you result as long as you have just **1 username for every Killerid**

```
SELECT `killerID`
    , COUNT(`killerID`) AS tot_kills
    , MIN(`Username`) AS username
FROM `kills`
INNER JOIN `players`
    ON `players`.`id` = `kills`.`killerid`
WHERE `killText` LIKE '%$gun%'
GROUP BY `killerID`
ORDER BY `tot_kills` DESC
```

Comment: Column 'id' in on clause is ambiguous

Comment: Try now.. added an Alias to the id column on the `on` clause

Answer (score 0):

SELECT kills.killerID, count(kills.killerID) as killTotal, players.Username 
        FROM kills, players
        WHERE kills.killText
        LIKE '%$gun%'
        AND players.ID` = kills.killerID
        GROUP BY kills.killerID 
ORDER BY kills.tot_kills DESC

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to learn some more about joins.
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

The best way is to have your own knowledge so you can be able to tune up your select queries.

Also put more indexes to your DB, and try to search and join by index.